# How do you write a method definition?

Tags: java, methods

This is my method signature and I'm writing this really long code that's supposed to update the student's mark and update the information in the grade book table given a student number and test number and yada yada yada. Anyway, before all of that, I'm going to have to write a method definition for a method, does anyone know a general format on how to do that? Heres my code so far by the way:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class GradeBook {
    private int numberofStudents;
    private int numberofTests;
    private int studId;

    private int [] [] table;

    private GradeBook()
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the number of student in the class");

        int numberofStudents = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter the number of tests taken for the term");
        int numberOfTests = keyboard.nextInt();

        table = new int [numberofStudents][numberofTests];
        System.out.println("Enter the students marks by ID number");

        System.out.println();
        for(int studId = 1; studId <= numberofStudents; studId++) {

                System.out.println('\n' + "Student ID: " + studId);
                for(int testNo =1; testNo <= numberOfTests; testNo++) {
                        System.out.println(" Test Number: " + testNo + '\t');

                        table [studId -1] [testNo - 1] = keyboard.nextInt();
        }
    }
}
    private void display()
    {
        int row, column;
        for(row =0; row<table.length; row++);
        {    
            System.out.print("Student ID: " + (row +1) + "Tests: ");

            for(column = 0; column < table[row]. length; column++)
                System.out.print(table[row] [column] + " ");

            System.out.println();
        }    
   }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GradeBook myBook = new GradeBook();
        myBook.display();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: `GradeBook()` is a constuctor, not a method... You do have a method `display()`, so I don't understand what you need.

Comment: no, I know it is a constructor, I want to know how to write a method deifniton

Comment: You already did. `private void display()`

Comment: From the official docs: [Defining Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)

Comment: And a more thorough explanation: [Java Methods](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_methods.htm)

Comment: It is not at all clear what you believe a "method definition" is or why you believe you have not already written one (`display()`).

Answer (score 0):

First, you show a class definition, not a method signature.

You might want to simplify that constructor so you aren't doing so much work there. Just initialize a table.

```
public class GradeBook {

    private int[][] table;

    public GradeBook(int students, int tests) {
        this.table = new int[students];
        for (int i = 0; i < students; i++) {
            this.table[i] = new int[tests];
        } 
        loadGrades();
    }
```

Here's examples of some "method definitions".

```
    public void loadGrades() {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        // TODO: load the test scores
    }

    public void getNumberOfStudents() {
        return this.table.length;
    }

    pubilc void display() {
        // TODO: Display all tests from all students
    }

    public void display(int studentId) {
       System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getTests(studentId));
    }

    public void setTest(int studentId, int testId, int grade) {
        this.table[studentId][testId] = grade;
    }

    public int[] getTests(int studentId) {
        return this.table[studentId];
    }
```

And I think you should move the prompts into the main method, not the object constructor.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the number of student in the class");
        int numberofStudents = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter the number of tests taken for the term");
        int numberOfTests = keyboard.nextInt();

        GradeBook g = new GradeBook(numberofStudents, numberOfTests);
        g.display();
    } 
}
```